# How can scripts extending VIM be managed?

Tags: vim

I use VIM for code development and lot of things. I see that there are lot of scripts, configurations shared at vim.org/scripts, also some at github. Time to time I would like to check which one of the scripts used by me were improved. This would need either manual checking of the scripts, but I am too lazy to do that. Writing some code to do the checking and upgrading is also an option, but I am not sure whether there is any agreement what all script contributors always follow. I would like to have a upgrader for these scripts. Is there any solution, or any practice for maintaining the VIM scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [pathogen.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) to make updating scripts stored on github trivial. Put `pathogen.vim` in `.vim/autoload` and add `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` into your `.vimrc` file to set up `pathogen`. Then in `.vim/bundle`, I `git clone [vim plugin]`, and updating is as simple as a `git pull` in the appropriate directories.

Comment: Thanks! Tim Pope made a good job, not only with pathogen but other vim scripts as well. http://github.com/tpope

Comment: This answer may be incomplete for some systems - http://www.adamlowe.me/2009/12/vim-destroys-all-other-rails-editors.html (note `filetype off` on top)

Answer (score 1):

What about `:h GetLatestVimScripts`?

Comment: It is great that VIM supports such a thing by default, but I checked some of my scripts and they do not support GetLatesVimScripts sadly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu Linux, you can install the vim addon manager:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-addon-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vim-addon-manager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905) (not that one that can be found in debian/ubuntu repositories). It puts plugins each into its own directory like it will be done with pathogen and also supports installation of plugins with one command. It is able to use mainstream git/mercurial/subversion/bazaar repository (if it is known by one of its authors) and install plugins from [vim.org](http://www.vim.org).